# Variable inside regex expression

Tags: regex, winforms, powershell

There are controls on the form that need to be searched inside the function, for this I decided to use `Controls.Find`, the input of the function is `$name`. In this case, the search works among the `TextBox` and add to the array for further work. `TextBox` names are represented as `IPTextBox1`, `IPTextBox2`, etc. As I wrote and how it does not work (`NetworkForm` is a form that contains all controls):

```
$TextBoxes = $NetworkForm.Controls.Find('/^([regex]::escape($name))[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{3}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}.{1}$/', 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the **generic question** in the title:

The **safest way to embed an arbitrary variable value in a regex is**:

- to **first *escape* the value with `[regex]::Escape($var)`**, which ensures that the value is treated as a *literal* (regex metacharacters such as `.` are `\`-escaped).
- and then **embed it in a *single-quoted* string via `-f`**, the (string) [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f), which allows embedding of RHS operands via indexed placeholders in the LHS format string; e.g., `{0}` is the 1st RHS operand, `{1}` the 2nd, and so on; use `{{` and `}}` to escape literal `{` and `}`.

For **example**, to construct a regex that matches an arbitrary value `$var` if preceded by one ore more digits (`\d+`) at a word boundary (`\b`) and if positioned at the end of the string (`$`)

```
# The value to embed in the regex, to be interpreted as a *literal*.
$var = '$'  

# Embed the escaped value in the regex.
# This results in the following regex - note the \-escaped $
#         \b\d+\$$
$regex = '\b\d+{0}$' -f [regex]::Escape($var)

# Perform matching:
'Cost: 20$' -match $regex  # -> $true
```

---

As for **your specific WinForm problem**:

[`.Controls.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find) on a WinForm form / control only allows searching for controls by their full, literal name, not by a regex.

Therefore you must enumerate all controls recursively and match their `.Name` property values individually.
Note that controls aren't *required* to have names.

Given that there is no built-in way to perform *recursive* enumeration of the controls contained inside a form / control, you must first implement that yourself, then filter by `-match` with a regex:

```
# Example:
#  Get-ChildControl -Recurse $form
function Get-ChildControl { 
  param([System.Windows.Forms.Control] $Control, [Switch] $Recurse) 
  foreach ($child in $Control.Controls) { 
    $child 
    if ($Recurse) { Get-ChildControl -Recurse:$Recurse $child } 
  } 
}

$regex = '^{0}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{3}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}.{1}$' -f [regex]::Escape($name)

$TextBoxes = Get-ChildControl -Recurse $NetworkForm | Where { $_.Name -cmatch $regex }
```

Note the use of `-cmatch` to perform case-*sensitive* matching.
`-match` (and its alias `-imatch`) are case-*insensitive* by default, as is PowerShell in general.

---

As for **the problems with your original regex**:

- Don't use `'...'` (literal strings) if you want to embed expressions such as `[regex]::escape($name)` in it.

  - To do so, you must use an expandable string (`"..."`) and embed the expression inside `$(...)`, not `(...)` - as shown in @TobyU's answer.
  - The alternative is to use `-f`, the string-formatting operator, as shown above.
- Generally, PowerShell has no regex-literal syntax, it just uses strings, so don't use `/.../` inside a string representing a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a string of the pattern before and use it afterwards.

```
$pattern = "/^($([regex]::escape($name)))[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{3}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}.{1}$/"
$TextBoxes = $NetworkForm.Controls.Find($pattern, 1)
```

Comment: Worth more clearly explain the problem. This is not the problem. You essentially just rewrote something else that has already been written.  Any text can come to the function input. I have a number of controls, called IP / DNS / MaskTextBox, I need to perform a search precisely by what came to the input, and not exactly by IP. The catch is that regex is incorrectly written, because I don’t know how to correctly use [regex]::escape(). And I use it to add a variable inside the regex. That is, the search should work somehow like Controls.Find ([$name]TextBox, $true), where $name can be anything